# Visual Basic Access: Too few parameters. Expected 1

Tags: sql, vba, sql-order-by, inner-join

```
    Private Sub createSequenceDataFiles_Sequence(sPath As String, sTableName As String, iSeqNo As Integer)
        Dim RST As DAO.Recordset
        Dim nIL As Long, nLastIL As Long
        Dim sSQL As String
        '
        ' Get the data from the table
        '
        sSQL = _
    " SELECT [“ & sTableName & “].IL, “ & _
    “ [XL]-[FIRST_XL]+1 AS XL_IDX, “ & _
    “ [“ & sTableName & “] “ & _
    “ FROM [“ & sTableName & “] “ & _
    “ INNER JOIN TBL_FIRST_XL_FOR_IL “ & _
    “ ON [“ & sTableName & “].IL = TBL_FIRST_XL_FOR_IL.IL “ & _
    “ ORDER BY [“ & sTableName & ”].IL, [XL]-[FIRST_XL]+1”
        Set RST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
        While Not RST.EOF
            nIL = RST("IL").Value
            If Not (nLastIL = nIL) Then
                '
                ' If we've already done one, close the file
                '
                If nLastIL > 0 Then Close #1
                '
                ' Open the file for the current in-line
                '
                Open sPath & "\WBS1\IL_" & Format(nIL, "0000") & ".pks" For Append As 1
            End If
            '
            ' Write the data
            '
            Write #1, iSeqNo, RST(“XL_IDX”).value + 1, RST("TIME").Value
            nLastIL = nIL
            RST.MoveNext
        Wend
        '
        ' Close
        '
        Set RST = Nothing
        Close
    End Sub
```

I am getting this error

Is there something wrong with this?

this is the entire code now i'm pretty sure it is the SQL bit which is the problem maybe my table names are wrong.

Comment: Are you sure this code that caused the error? Can you post more code for this? What is `sTableName` content?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I've added more of the code now

Comment: Here is the SQL produced by your formula (using "aTable" for the table name): `SELECT [aTable].IL,  [XL]-[FIRST_XL]+1 AS XL_IDX,  **[aTable]**  FROM [aTable]  INNER JOIN TBL_FIRST_XL_FOR_IL  ON [aTable].IL = TBL_FIRST_XL_FOR_IL.IL  ORDER BY [aTable].IL, **[XL]-[FIRST_XL]+1**`. The items in "**" are referenced as fields in the statement, but they can't be, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tables and/or fieldnames in your SQL query don't match your database structure.

This includes any value in the `sTableName` parameter.

Just check and make sure all the fields match exactly and you should find the culprit.

**EDIT**: Just noticed this in the SELECT part

```
    “ [“ & sTableName & “] “ & _
```

You shouldn't be referencing the whole table in the `SELECT` portion of your statement, what happens if you remove this line from the SQL statement?

Comment: there was a field name missing after this part, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Glad to help. Mind accepting the answer since it resolved your problem? I need my Internet points haha